# How to access globlal variable within a class method using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, variables, global

I'm having an issue where I have a class method that creates a batch file and stores the name of the file in a variable called "filename". I have another method that runs the batch file calling the "filename" created in another method. But i get the response Class object has no attribute "filename". How can I create this variable in one method and call it in another method within the same class?

I've tried setting self.filename = filename. I've tried setting the global filename = None outside of the class and then setting filename within the class **init** itself. I've included the snippet codes below:

```
class SNMPPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('SNMP Get Set Test')
        global filename
        self.init_gui()

    def create_batch(self):
        i = 0
        #path = os.getcwd()
        global filename
        #ping_set = 'ping -n 1 ' + e1.get() + ' | find "TTL=" >null\nif errorlevel 1 (\n    echo host not reachable\n    pause\n)\n'
        snmp_get = 'snmpget' + " -Os" + " -mall " + "-c " + self.e3.get() + ' -v2c' + ' ' + self.e1.get() + ' ' + self.e2.get() + "\n"
        snmp_set = 'snmpset' + " -Os" + " -mall " + "-c " + self.e3.get() + ' -v2c' + ' ' + self.e1.get() + ' ' + self.e2.get() + \
                    ' i' + ' 1\n'
        timeout = 'timeout ' + self.e4.get() + '\n'
        filename = path + '\\SNMPBatchrun' + getdatetime('datetime') + ".bat"
        with open(filename, 'w+') as outfile:
            while i < 10:
                #outfile.write(ping_set)
                outfile.write(snmp_get)
                outfile.write(snmp_set)
                outfile.write(timeout)
                i += 1
        loggermodule.module_logger.debug('Batch File Created: {}'.format(filename))
        logger.debug('Batch file created: {}'.format(filename))


    def start_batch(self):
        try:
            global filename
            logger.debug('Starting batch file execution')
            loggermodule.module_logger.debug('Starting batch file execution')
            #s = subprocess.check_output([filename]).decode('utf-8')
            process = subprocess.Popen([filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            output, code = process.communicate()
            self.root.update()

            ''' Logger'''
            for line in code.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
                if 'Waiting for' not in line:
                    logger.debug(line)
                    loggermodule.module_logger.debug(line)
                for line in output.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
                    if 'Waiting for' not in line:
                        logger.debug(line)
                        loggermodule.module_logger.debug(line)
            loggermodule.module_logger.debug("Batch job completed")
            logger.debug("Batch job completed")
            # with open(log_file, 'w+') as outfile:
            #    for line in s.splitlines():
            #        outfile.write(line)
            return self.output
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            loggermodule.module_logger.debug(e)
            loggermodule.module_logger.debug("There was an error, Batch file stopped. Check Log file")
```

```
'SNMPPage' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

I expect the file to be created with create_batchfile (which is is successfully), but then when I run the method start_batchfile, it fails with SNMPPage has no attribute "filename"

Comment: does this filename have to be shared between all the class instances or between same object methods?

Comment: @LiorCohen really just between the two object methods. One creates a batch file and the other runs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your clarification in the comment.

In order to share a variable between methods, this should be an object attribute.
I don't know why it did not work for you but you should use this basic pattern.

```
class SNMPPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, root=None):
    self.filename = None # this is not a must but a very good practice
    ....

  def create_batch(self):
    self.filename = 'foo'

  def start_batch(self):
    # use self.filename
    print(self.filename)
```

Comment: I appreciate this. It worked this time around. Not sure what the difference was, because I had tried your solution earlier and it still failed, but now its ok. The logging aspect is still a bit off but i'll debug that on my own. I'm still working on classes. I thought that once a variable is created in a local scope within a method, it's "destroyed" after use and cant be used by a different method.

Comment: you right regarding local variable but self.filenmae is not a local variable it is an object attribute (what call member in other langs)